# preg_match multiple pattern

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match

Previous questions explain some issues like this, but I couldn't implement solution for my issue.

I tried to create pattern for:
 1. Big Character
 2. Small Character
 3. Number
 4. SpecialChar

All this conditions must contain my string.
I can check conditions 1,2,3 with:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]
```

I can check condition number 4 (special chars) with:

```
[[:punct:]]
```

But I can't get this combination of them to work:

```
$p = "aAbB4#"; //correct string

if(!preg_match('/([0-9A-Za-z]{4,50}|[[:punct:]])/',$p)){
      $p = "Not all credentinals are correct";
}
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for [`\A(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*\d)(?=\P{P}*\p{P})[a-zA-Z0-9\p{P}]{4,50}\z`](https://regex101.com/r/yI7pT8/1)

Comment: Are you saying it must end with a special char? Or that a special char is valid anywhere in the string?

Comment: It must contains special char. For example:
E#3a1d, ?8dDsS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive look-ahead matching for this, i.e. put every character into `(?=)` group:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[[:punct:]]).{4,50}$/', $p)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: yeeahh, man, It seems to working.
I try to understand that. 
Are you using groups like (?=.*....) ??
Tanks you